# Positioning of Superfish sub menu text and drop-down menus on the right

Tags: css, superfish

I am trying to align the text in sub-menu items to the right rather than the left in a Superfish menu.

I was able to align the drop-down to the right side of the top level menu item but cannot seem to figure out the text alignment.

Also, how would I go about having further children menus open to the left rather than the right? Since the nav bar is located to the right in the design, I do not want menu items opening outside the confines of the content box (to the right).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** - I removed the demo link because I decided to go another route, Superfish was making me want to rip my hair out. But it would still be nice to know if there is a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is possible, Ive heard a few people try it.

I hear this page mate provide some help:

[link](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/supposition-test/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize what you are linking to and only provide the link for reference.